# How to use SupportSQLiteDatabase with exoplayer's SimpleCache?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to use room with exoplayer, but as `SupportSQLDatabase` is an interface.

Here is my code.

```kotlin
            val evictor = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(maxCacheSize)
            val simpleCache = SimpleCache(File(context.cacheDir, "media"), evictor, object : DatabaseProvider{
                override fun getWritableDatabase(): SQLiteDatabase {
                    return  RoomDatabase.openHelper.writableDatabase <- returns SupportSQLDatabase
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                }
    
                override fun getReadableDatabase(): SQLiteDatabase {
                    return  RoomDatabase.openHelper.readableDatabase
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                }
    
            })
            return CacheDataSource(
                simpleCache,
                defaultDatasourceFactory.createDataSource(),
                FileDataSource(),
                CacheDataSink(simpleCache, maxFileSize),
                CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE or CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR,
                null
            )
```

Using SimpleCache without DatabaseProvider is deprecated

Is there any alterantive to `SimpleCache` which is compatible with room?

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val simpleCache = SimpleCache(File(context.cacheDir, "media"), evictor, ExoDatabaseProvider(context))
```

This seem to work